# jquery on click event, opens on second click, not initial click

Tags: jquery, onclick, modal-dialog

I feel I am missing something simple. I am unable to get a modal dialog to work when it is dynamically added to the DOM. It works on the second click but won't work on the initial click.

How would I get this to fire on the first click? Any thoughts are appreciated.
Thanks

```
    $("#page3placeholder").on("click", "#open-popup", function () {
      $(this).magnificPopup({ blah blah });
    });
```

code to add to dom

```
 $("#page3placeholder").html('<button id="open-popup" style="margin-top:100px; margin-left:100px;" style="display:none;"  >Open popup</button>');
```

Comment: not 100% clear, can you post the full code?

Comment: Can you post the code that adds it to the Dom?

Comment: place an alert before your plugin call inside click handler...and see if the problem is with `.magnificPopup` or your click handler.

Comment: i did an alert and it did fire when clicked the first time however the modal dialog box would not launch

Answer (score 0):

You may find the usage of `$("#page3placeholder").click(function() { $(#open-popup).foo... }` easier to use / more clear.

Do you have any invisible element in your "way" when clicking, that disappears on first click?
i.e. is "#open-popup" in the way being at `ocupacity: 0`?

Comment: The OP stated " I am unable to get a modal dialog to work when it is dynamically added to the DOM." Your example does not work with dynamically added elements.

Comment: You can assign events to basically any elements, no matter if they were dynamically added or not. It's all a matter of WHEN. You can not assign to it, before it is there. That's pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: You should use `.on()`'s event delegation syntax to manage dynamically added elements. The code you posted won't work unless it's executed in the callback of the elements being added.